# Google navigation audio stops - not pauses - audio playback

Tags: audio, google-maps-navigation

I'm not sure if this is the place to ask for help or not, but I'm getting desperate at this point, so apologies if this not the correct forum...

Google maps will stop audio playback.
I have tried different map navigation systems, and different podcast players and it almost always seems to happen. Sometimes, as soon as the map app is loaded, other times not.

This isssue is slowly driving me insane and making me really regret buying this phone. (Which is a Motorola Moto G Android 4.4.4)

Please advise what my next step should be.

I've managed to get the result from a logging app which produced the following output

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/dalvikvm(26340): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 11...
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(26340): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {41f60e60}
I/LibraryLoader(26340): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
I/chromium(26340): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController(26340): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
E/AudioManagerAndroid(26340): BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
I/Adreno-EGL(26340): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
I/Adreno-EGL(26340): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
I/Adreno-EGL(26340): Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
I/Adreno-EGL(26340): Local Branch: 
I/Adreno-EGL(26340): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
I/Adreno-EGL(26340): Local Patches: NONE
I/Adreno-EGL(26340): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
D/AudioManagerAndroid(26340): ==> onReceive: s=0, m=0, n=h2w, sb=true
D/AudioManagerAndroid(26340): reportUpdate: state=0, devices=[Speakerphone, Headset earpiece]
I/dalvikvm(26730): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 11...
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(26730): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {41f5b7a8}
I/LibraryLoader(26730): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
I/chromium(26730): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController(26730): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
E/AudioManagerAndroid(26730): BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
I/Adreno-EGL(26730): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
I/Adreno-EGL(26730): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
I/Adreno-EGL(26730): Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
I/Adreno-EGL(26730): Local Branch: 
I/Adreno-EGL(26730): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
I/Adreno-EGL(26730): Local Patches: NONE
I/Adreno-EGL(26730): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
D/AudioManagerAndroid(26730): ==> onReceive: s=0, m=0, n=h2w, sb=true
D/AudioManagerAndroid(26730): reportUpdate: state=0, devices=[Speakerphone, Headset earpiece]
D/dalvikvm(26730): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4803K, 29% free 12245K/17224K, paused 18ms, total 23ms
```

I have no clue if this helps in any way. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your phone connected to the car via Bluetooth? The log notes that "Bluetooth permission is missing"

Comment: Not connected via Bluetooth, no.
Though Bluetooth was active.

Comment: I tried with Bluetooth turned off. The result is the same, still logging that 'BLUETOOTH permission is missing!'

Comment: that proably is unrelated to the problem. It seems an app is trying to use Bluetooth without permission.

Comment: The audio still stops.
I don't see anything else in the log that looks like it's complaining about anything. Any suggestions?